# How to make sublime text 3 to automatically fill the "find" filled with current selection when searching in one or multiple files

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm experiencing a strange behavior in macOS, when I've selected text and hit SHIFT-COMMAND-F the "find" field is left empty and not filled with the selected text, every time I have to manually copy or insert it.

In Windows this behavior is different whenever I hit SHIFT-ALT-F the "find" field is filled with the currently selected text.

How to fix this? Can't find any option in the preferences.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The setting you want to turn on is this one:

```json
    // If true, the selected text will be copied into the find panel when it's
    // shown.
    // On Mac, this value is overridden in the platform specific settings.
    "find_selected_text": true,
```

This is a direct copy from the default preferences. As seen here, it defaults to being enabled on Linux and Windows, but on MacOS the platform specific settings that ship with Sublime turn it off, so on that OS you need to copy this setting into your user preferences in order to turn it on.

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed this when looked into the preferences.